# Runtime appconfig value changes

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I want to ask about reading the app config property value.

I can change some of the app config property value during runtime and I could use that property value in my code. So, how to get that runtime changed app config property value in my code? Is there any options to get the runtime changed app config value in C#.NET?

Comment: Are you using ConfigurationManager ? check out `RefreshSection` .. Can you post some code ?

Comment: Why would you want to change the app config file while the program is running?  The app config should contain the parameters that the program needs when it runs - e.g., the proper URL to use for a web service if you have multiple environments (development, test, production, etc).  Making it editable at run time seems to be contrary to its purpose, IMO.

Comment: based upon the app config option only the trace will be taken .so if user want to off the trace option while running the application ,the trace log wont be take .so that purpose only i want to change the appconfig file.plz help me if u known

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After saving the changes to the app config, do like this

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);
```

to get the updated values.

Have a look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much its working fine.but i have edit the appconfig file manuallty ,its program installation path ,i want to get that external appconfig edited value to my code,i could used code based upon the appconfig value.so i want to get the external modified appconfig value.If u know plz help me.

Comment: @dinu - sorry dinu, but i am not getting you. Can you explain it more clearly.

Comment: based upon the app config option only the trace will be taken in my aplication.so if user want to off the trace option while running the application ,the trace log wont be take .so that purpose only i want to change the appconfig file in runtime.based upon the changes the application trace log will be enable /disable.i coded like that.but i dont know how to get the runtime modified appconfig value by coding.

Comment: This doesn't work. If I modify the appConfig during runtime the values do not change until I next re-run the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConfigurationManager` to modify the config files and then use the `RefreshSection` after saving the settings but how are you trying to access the new information in case you are using `GetSection` then its unlikely you would get the changes as its getting read from cache. You will have to use `OpenExeConfiguration` i think to read the new changes.

It is not a good practice to change the configurations at runtime you should choose to revisit your purpose once again

Comment: Thank you very much its working fine.but i have edit the appconfig file manuallty ,its program installation path ,i want to get that external appconfig edited value to my code,i could used code based upon the appconfig value.so i want to get the external modified appconfig value.If u know plz help me.